# Comparison Test for Improper Integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm supposed to find if the the following integral converges or diverges by comparison:

$$\int_0^\infty\sin(x^2)\cdot e^{-x} dx$$

It would be easy to take away $e^{-x}$ and solve using Fresnel but I'm not supposed to use that. The integral converges. Any suggestions?

Comment: Bounding sin by 1 does the trick

Comment: $e^{-x}$ isn't your problem.  In fact, it is your friend.

Comment: So $e^{-x}$ is greater than the original and thus it converges?

Comment: Yes exactly{}{}{}{}{}

Comment: Wow, I thought that was too easy and had to be wrong

Comment: @Max not this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\sin(x^2)|\leq 1$, you have
$$|\sin(x^2)\cdot e^{-x}|\leq e^{-x} $$
and
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x=1 $$
By the comparison test, your integral is convergent.